# Python3: can.Notifier, can.Logger doesn't write to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, can-bus

using can.Logger on python 3.9.2  i'm not able to write a log file with everything that comes on can bus

my python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import can
import time

bus = can.Bus(interface='socketcan',
              channel='can2')

fileName = "test.asc"
notifier = can.Notifier(bus, [can.Printer(), can.Logger(fileName, 'a')])


tm1 = time.perf_counter()
while True:
    tm2 = time.perf_counter()
    if tm2 >= tm1 + 5:
        notifier.stop()
        tm1=time.perf_counter()
        notifier = can.Notifier(bus, [can.Printer(), can.Logger(fileName, 'a')])
```

when I run my script, the "test.asc" file is correctly created but there's nothing inside.

the script give me an output like this:

```
2
Timestamp: 1647881138.770576    ID: 0302b0a0    X                DLC:  8    00 00 55 00 8d 00 00 aa     Channel: can2
Timestamp: 1647881139.770898    ID: 0302b0a0    X                DLC:  8    00 00 55 00 8d 00 00 aa     Channel: can2
Timestamp: 1647881140.770732    ID: 0302b0a0    X                DLC:  8    00 00 55 00 8d 00 00 aa     Channel: can2
Timestamp: 1647881141.770435    ID: 0302b0a0    X                DLC:  8    00 00 55 00 8d 00 00 aa     Channel: can2
T
```

the result I would like to obtain is to log everything that comes to me on the can bus until the script is interrupted

***EDIT***

i've seen that the problem probaly is where i declare notifier for the second time.
but it is necessary for me to block the notifier every 5 seconds. how can I restart it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not possible to restart can.Notifier.

but to write a log file with everything that comes on can bus you can use bus.recv()

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import can
import time

bus = can.Bus(interface='socketcan', channel='can2')

fileName = "test.log"

while True:
    with open("/home/pi/"+fileName, "a+") as f1:
        message = bus.recv()
        f1.write(str(message)+'\n')

    time.sleep(0.05)
```